# Single Key in Array Merge in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have an array of items, in it is 1 key "locations" that will contain another array of items.

Is there a way to merge this key, without having to loop the parent array?  I am working with wordpress and PHP.

**Example Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test Property 1
            [locations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Term Object
                        (
                            [term_id] => 334
                            [name] => Los Angeles
                            [slug] => los-angeles
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test Property 2
            [locations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Term Object
                        (
                            [term_id] => 335
                            [name] => New York
                            [slug] => new-york
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Test Property 3
            [locations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Term Object
                        (
                            [term_id] => 336
                            [name] => Baltimore
                            [slug] => baltimore
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to merge only the 'locations' key, so I am left with a seperate array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 334
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 335
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 336
        )

)
```

Comment: Why are you so afraid of loops? This __always__ will be done with a loop, either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: Wouldnt that be a bigger memory hit... this is a wordpress site... already mem heavy ;)

Comment: Until you test - you can't say.

Comment: HA.  true, but I do have a few years hosting experience with nothing but wordpress sites to know how heavy it "can" be ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit looping:

```
$source_array = [/* Your array here */];
$new_array = [];
foreach ($source_array as $item) {
    $new_array[] = ['term_id' => $item['locations'][0]->term_id];
}
```

Implicit looping, one of solutions:

```
$source_array = [/* Your array here */];
$new_array = array_reduce(
    $source_array,
    function($t, $v) { $t[] = ['term_id' => $v['locations'][0]->term_id]; return $t; },
    []
);
```